# Unicode not rendering in Django-Rest-Framework browsable API in Chrome

Tags: python, django, unicode, django-rest-framework, content-type

I am trying to display a unicode value `u'\u20b9'` from my SQLite database, using the browsable API of django-rest-framework 3.1.3

I don't get the expected value `₹` for currency_symbol, it returns the following, depending on the browser:

> ***Chrome 49.0.2623.110 (64-bit):***
>
> Browsable API: `""` (Blank String)
>
> JSON: `"â‚¹"`
>
> ***Safari 9.1 (10601.5.17.4):***
>
> Browsable API: `₹`
>
> JSON: `"â‚¹"`
>
> ***CURL:***
>
> JSON: `₹`

**How do I get it to consistently display `₹`?**

Comment: Turns out it was a browser bug.

Answer (score 2):

You likely miss the system language settings available within Django. Depending on your stack (apache or supervisor do remove default system settings) you will need to define it explicitly.

The reason is, unicode is for Python internal specific. You need to encode the unicode into an output format. Could be utf8, or any iso code.

Note that this is deferent from the header`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` which goal is to decode the file into unicode using the utf-8 charset. It doesn't mean that any output within that file code will be converted using utf8.

Comment: I used `sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')` in `settings.py` and the `UnicodeEncodeError` went away, but I am still getting `"â‚¹"` instead of `₹`

Comment: iirc, this won't work because a couple of initialization will already be done and I've seen places where setdefaultencoding requires tricks to work (can't remember which ones though)

Comment: I added some additional information to the question, at this point I believe it is a browser rendering/headers issue as I can see the expected unicode `₹` when making a CURL request to the URL. Might be related to https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/2891